# How to convert a property value from UTF8 to ascii in Ant

Tags: encoding, ant

Suppose I have a property

```
${test}=íñü
```

In Ant, is there a method to convert this property value to \uxxxx?

I know Ant can convert a file using native2ascii.

How about a property value?

Update: The reason I ask this question is because I want to run a bat file in ant, the path of the bat file contains some non-Ascii char:

```
${test}=íñü
<target name="help">
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="${test}.bat"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The error is that system cannot find the path. I think it relates to how the path is encoded. But escape the path from UTF8 to ASCII doesn't help to resove the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`loadresource` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) with an [encoding filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#escapeunicode).

This example sets the property `test2` from `test`:

```
<property name="test" value="íñü" />
<loadresource property="test2">
  <string value="${test}" />
  <filterchain>
    <escapeunicode/>
  </filterchain>
</loadresource>
<echo encoding="utf8" message="'${test}' maps to '${test2}'" />
```

Result:

```
[echo] 'íñü' maps to '\u00ed\u00f1\u00fc'
```

The `loadresource` task requires Ant 1.7 or newer.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. it works. The reason I ask it is because I have another problem. But it seems that this doesn't eventually help me to solve the other problem. Please see my updated post

Comment: I don't have a windows machine handy right now to experiment.  Can you get the same to work from a simple .bat file?  It might be that The Java file.encoding is mismatched with that of the OS - maybe windows is expecting CP-1252?

Comment: Did you mean to run the .bat from cmd? It works, but cmd is not able to display the file name

Comment: I meant running íñü.bat from another batch file, one that uses utf-8 encoding.  But it sounds like it might well work... Like I said, I don't have the OS to investigate this.